# What is the difference between Paypal Business and Paypal Enterprise?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

As a new developer, I found there are two very similar types of Paypal from Paypal Developer's page: https://developer.paypal.com/home/

`For Business` and `For Enterprise` (I understand `For Marketplaces and Platforms` is meant to be used entirely different use casaes)

I saw "Manage Risk" under `for Enterprise`  -- that seems to be the only difference from For Business -- but even a small business needs to manage its risk, doesn't it?

Can someone give me a high level explanation, when should I use `For Business` and when should I use `for Enterprise` from the following perspective?

1. how much extra functionality does `for enterprise` offer comparing to `for business`?
2. how much extra complexity for the developers to implement the integration comparing to the later?

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of scale. The product offerings in the Enterprise section aren't designed for or marketed toward small and medium sized businesses. What exactly that means, and whether there might be a particular exception to something you need, will vary.

If you have to ask whether the Enterprise section applies to you, it doesn't.

Comment: I am building a small site to enable home made arts selling, so technically it’s a market place. But right now I am using the business payment logic, I.e the buyers pay to my account (the marketplace owner’s account) and then I will pay the sellers on the marketplace. How difficult would it be to change from my current method to the PayPal Markeplace and Platform way?